# Moving from one tab to other using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have a tab layout having 4 tabs, the view pager is replaced with fragments, i have one button in tab 3 (i mean in fragment 3). On clicking of that button i should go to fragment 1 (inside tab 1), how to achieve this ?
 I am just able to replacing the fragment 3 with fragment 1. but the tabs also should change .

Comment: Please add more details about your problem and your own efforts this far to solve the problem so that people can help you better. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try this use **`ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int position)`**

> **`void setCurrentItem (int item)`**
>
> Set the currently selected page. If the `ViewPager` has already been through its first layout with its current `adapter` there will be a smooth animated transition between the current item and the specified item.

```
 tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0)
        }
    });
```

Comment: how to get the view pager reference in the fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

Prem's answer is right!
If you want to access view pager inside fragment from Activity just do it like that in ***fragment*** view click listener

```
((YOUR_VIEWPAGER_ACTIVITY)getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(int position)
```

Note: Make sure **mViewPager is public** in Activity